# How to get library full-native name on cmake?

Tags: cmake

I need to pass the native name (libfoo.so or foo.dll) of a builded library to a add_custom_command.

How can I get the full library name of a target?

the property `LOCATION`has it but with the full path. The property OUTPUT_NAME does not return anything.

Comment: In which part of `add_custom_command()` do you need it? Would the generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` help you?

Comment: On the arguments part. What's a generator expression? I've tried your proposal and it expands to the full path while I would need only the filename :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the generator expression `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:tgt>`, where `tgt` is the logical CMake name of your target.

Example:

```
add_library(myLib a.cpp)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT someOutput
  COMMAND myProcessor --input $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:myLib> --output someOutput
  # ...
)
```

For more on generator expressions, refer to the [documentation of `add_custom_command()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command) (for CMake 2.x) or to the dedicated [generator expression documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) (for CMake 3+).