# CMake how to get binary target complete directory and name on Windows

Tags: cmake

Is there a way in CMake to find a binary target complete name (mybin.exe) by inspecting target properties? Like

`get_target_property(EXENAME targetname OUTPUT_NAME)` (or RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME)

Or I have to use a custom command like in [How to get library full-native name on cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549853/how-to-get-library-full-native-name-on-cmake)

With get_target_property seems I'm only able to get the "logical" target name out of it (mybin), with no other information. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: In most cases you should use `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` generator expressions instead of accessing filename-related target properties. Note, that even `OUTPUT_NAME` property is not set for the target by default. CMake treats this as needing to use target name as the name of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason this is not possible without generator expressions: There are multi configuration generators such as the Visual Studio generators that create a build system for multiple build configurations (Release, Debug, ...) in a single CMake configuration run (`cmake -S ... -B ...`). It's even the default to create binaries in a directory with a name matching the configuration built.

Depending on what you want to do with the information, there are some alternatives:

- You may be able to use generator expressions, e.g. if you need the information as part of [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html), [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) or similar. Several target properties also allow for use of generator expressions.
- You may be able to establish the desired directory structure during an install step, see [the `install()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html).
- You may be able to get the build system to generate the files in a specific location e.g. by setting [the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`. Note that this will still result in configuration dependent subdirectories being created for multi configuration generators, unless the variable value contains a generator expression. (You could, simply be adding `$<0:>`, but this could easily result in binaries of different configurations overwriting one another.)

  If you cannot specify this in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`, via command line or cmake presets, you could still use a path relative to [`CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html); this should make the binaries easy to locate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I had forgot the ominous Visual Studio and Xcode generators indeed...

Answer (score 2):

In the end that is a matter of doing:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${your_target}
    POST_BUILD
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${your_dir}
    COMMAND echo "$<TARGET_FILE:${your_target}>" > "exename.txt"
    DEPENDS ${your_target} ${another_target}
    VERBATIM
    )
```

so that exename.txt contains the full path to the executable target
Didn't find a way to do st like:

```
set(EXENAME "$<TARGET_FILE:${your_target}>")
```

anyway...

Comment: Following the above solution